# Highcharts setExtremes blanking the graph

Tags: highcharts

I am working on a graph that i want to show between two dates. Sometimes there may not be any data at the start or end of the date range.

I tried to use the setExtremes options but when i do it blanks the graph, see example below

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/353609/

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(DateFromMin, DateToMax, true,false);
```

If you comment out the setExtremes function above the graph generate but when its in the code it doesn't

Same thing happens if i use the min and max on the x axis. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using string in `setExtreme` with strings. `DateFromMin` and `DateToMax` needs to be numbers.Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/sqbp180g/1/

Comment: Additionally, you should try to convert your timestamps to milliseconds and change your xAxis to `datetime`, it could simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks a million, I can't believe it was something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the the min and max figures were stings instead ints - thanks to ewolden in the comments for the answer